# Functions and Combinatorics

Tags: combinatorics, permutations, functional-equations

> If a function $f$ is defined as $f : \{1, 2, 3, 4\}\to \{1, 2, 3, 4\}$ such that
> $$f(f(x)) = f(x), \ \ \ \ \forall x\in \{1, 2, 3, 4\}.$$
> and $S$ is the number of such functions then find $S$.

We can easily figure out that one way of doing this is $f(x) =x$. Then $$f(f(x)) = f(x) = x.$$
Or we can have some cases like $f(i) = i$ only for some elements and others are mapped carefully according to the conditions.

How should I proceed? Also can you suggest some alternate methods.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

$\newcommand{\ran}{\operatorname{ran}}$I’ll get you started. The requirement that $f\big(f(x)\big)=f(x)$ means that every element of the range of $f$ must be a fixed point of $f$, i.e., a point such that $f(x)=x$.

- If $\ran(f)=\{1,2,3,4\}$, then $f$ must be the identity function: $f(x)=x$ for all $x\in\{1,2,3,4\}$.
- If $\ran(f)=\{1,2,3\}$, then we must have $f(1)=1$, $f(2)=2$, and $f(3)=3$, but $f(4)$ can be any of $1,2$, and $3$; how many different functions does that allow? And much the same thing happens when the range of $f$ is any $3$-element subset of $\{1,2,3,4\}$.
- If $\ran(f)=\{1,2\}$, then $f(1)=1$ and $f(2)=2$, but each of $f(3)$ and $f(4)$ can be either $1$ or $2$; how many different functions does that allow? And again, much the same thing happens when the range of $f$ is any $2$-element subset of $\{1,2,3,4\}$.
- Now what happens when $f$ is constant, i.e., has a $1$-element range?

Comment: Yes. We get the correct answer which is 41. Thanks

Comment: @ishwarbb: You’re welcome.

Comment: [OEIS A000248](https://oeis.org/A000248)

Comment: @Henry What is this link you sent?

Comment: @ishwarbb - it is a link to the number of such functions: $1$ starting with $\{1\}$, $3$ starting with $\{1,2\}$, $10$ starting with $\{1,2,3\}$, $41$ starting with $\{1,2,3,4\}$, etc.